# How not to show the email body?

Tags: android, email

I'm developing an android app and I want to send an email.

The following code works fine, but I need one thing in special…

This code, after the user chose an email app option, will open the chosen client showing the email body to let him to click to send.

The problems is that in the email body I want to send a password. So, anyone can click in resend button and easily view the password without sending.

I want to send an email without showing the body or just send without showing email app options… (I already have the destination email saved).

Anyone know how to?

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { mailRecover });
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);

App.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.send_password_recover)));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone know how to?

Write your own email client, perhaps using the JavaMail port for Android.

When you use `ACTION_SEND`, you are asking somebody else's app to send something on your app's behalf. You, however, cannot force those other apps to do anything, such as not show the email body to the user.